# jupyterlab/hub-extension@0.12.0" is not compatible with the current JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub, jupyter-lab, jupyter-console

I want to install the littlest jupyterhub via .gitlab-ci.yml in a subdomain.
Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml. I get this error message. I need a little help to fix this error message. I know the littlest jupyterhub is still in beta.
Is it possible to add packages like pandas, mathplotlib to install with a shell script?

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest-jupyterhub/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.py | sudo python3 - --admin klein
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  2682  100  2682    0     0  24381      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 24381
Checking if TLJH is already installed...
Setting up hub environment
Installed python & virtual environment
Set up hub virtual environment
Setting up TLJH installer...
Setup tljh package
Starting TLJH installer...
> /usr/bin/npm pack @jupyterlab/hub-extension
Incompatible extension:

"@jupyterlab/hub-extension@0.12.0" is not compatible with the current JupyterLab
Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab              Extension        Package
>=0.18.3 <0.19.0        >=0.19.1 <0.20.0 @jupyterlab/application
>=0.18.3 <0.19.0        >=0.19.1 <0.20.0 @jupyterlab/apputils

Found compatible version: 0.11.0
> /usr/bin/npm pack @jupyterlab/hub-extension@0.11.0
> node /opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js install
> node /opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js run build
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/tljh/hub/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tljh/installer.py", line 447, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/tljh/hub/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tljh/installer.py", line 436, in main
    ensure_jupyterhub_service(HUB_ENV_PREFIX)
  File "/opt/tljh/hub/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tljh/installer.py", line 141, in ensure_jupyterhub_service
    systemd.reload_daemon()
  File "/opt/tljh/hub/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tljh/systemd.py", line 19, in reload_daemon
    ], check=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 418, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemctl', 'daemon-reload']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Downloading traefik 1.6.5...
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1



image: ubuntu:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y curl git ssh python3 rsync sudo
  - git submodule update --init --recursive

stages:
    - test
    - deploy

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - curl
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest-jupyterhub/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.py | sudo python3 - --admin admin

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - curl
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest jupyterhub/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.py | sudo python3 - --admin adminn
    - mkdir .public
    - cp  -r * .public
    - mv .public public
    - mkdir "${HOME}/.ssh"
    - echo "${SSH_HOST_KEY}" > "${HOME}/.ssh/known_hosts"
    - echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa"
    - chmod 700 "${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa"
    - rsync -hrvz --delete --exclude=_ public/ user@example.com:www/jupyter/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```